# PDF Links in Adobe Reader 11.0.11 dont work

Tags: java, pdf, xslt, apache-fop

I am working on a piece of software that uses FOP to create PDF documents from XSL Transforms.

The output is simply a pretty rendered list of information (details really don't matter), but at the bottom, there is a link that takes the user to a more in-depth document (even though these are for printing... was a requirement). This link is a relative link, constructed via:

```
<fo:basic-link external-destination="raw.pdf?unique=XXXXXXXX">
    read more
</fo:basic-link>
```

This links displays fine, and when its viewed in Adobe Reader XI (11.0.10 and below), the link works fine, and when the PDF is viewed offline (not from the Web Browser, incidentally, IE only), an error is displayed saying the link cant be found.

However, when I view the document in Adobe Reader 11.0.11, then if I click the link (in browser OR offline), nothing happens.

I have checked the [Change Log](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/ReleaseNotes/11/11.0.11.html) for the latest version, but there is nothing super helpful (the one possibly useful entry is 3688510, but that no longer exists in their bug database).

Does anyone know why this has happened?

I am currently experimenting with defining concrete links (including full path and host), but this is not ideal as the installation for this software is not really meant to know about where it is (still possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a security enhancement in Adobe Reader 11.0.11.

[Link to Adobe Forum][1]

In particular [Rave (Adobe Employee) answers here](https://forums.adobe.com/message/7601481#7601481):

> *3. Re: Links in PDF stop working after updating to Reader 11.0.11*
>
> This browser workflow has been purposely blocked because of security bug.
>
> We allow destination that starts with http: or https. Also if the path is a platform path (non-string) we block it.
>
> We are investigating more on it. I will keep you updated on the same.

The effects of this security fix seem to go beyond this, though.

A possible work-around seems to be to disable the fix via the registry.

E.g. [AdriàAdell (Community Member) answered on a parallel thread](https://forums.adobe.com/message/7732115#7732115):

> *23. Re: Since upgrading to 11.0.11, relative cross document links while viewing PDF in the browser are no longer functioning*
>
> This solution has worked for me.
>   I have created a reg file for X/XI/DC versions of Reader/Acrobat and 32/64 bits.
>
> ```
> ;Adobe X - 32 bit
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\10.0\FeatureState]
> "3836774"=dword:00000000
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\10.0\FeatureState]
> "3836774"=dword:00000000
>
> ;Adobe XI - 32 bit
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\11.0\FeatureState]
> "3836776"=dword:00000000
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\11.0\FeatureState]
> "3836776"=dword:00000000
>
> ;Adobe DC - 32 bit
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\12.0\FeatureState]
> "3836780"=dword:00000000
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\12.0\FeatureState]
> "3836780"=dword:00000000
>
> ;Adobe X - 64 bit
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\10.0\FeatureState]
> "3836774"=dword:00000000
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\10.0\FeatureState]
> "3836774"=dword:00000000
>
> ;Adobe XI - 64 bit
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\11.0\FeatureState]
> "3836776"=dword:00000000
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\11.0\FeatureState]
> "3836776"=dword:00000000
>
> ;Adobe DC - 64 bit
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\12.0\FeatureState]
> "3836780"=dword:00000000
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat\12.0\FeatureState]
> "3836780"=dword:00000000
> ```

and [later added](https://forums.adobe.com/message/7948628#7948628):

> *30. Re: Since upgrading to 11.0.11, relative cross document links while viewing PDF in the browser are no longer functioning*
>
> On the last update of Reader, the regedit must be changed in:
>
> ```
> ;Adobe DC - 32 bit
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\DC\FeatureState]
> "3836780"=dword:00000000
>
> ;Adobe DC - 64 bit
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\DC\FeatureState]
> "3836780"=dword:00000000
> ```

[1]: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1849489